# Troubles using ng-if inside html template of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have recently start working with Angular.JS, and i have arrived to a scenario that i don't know how to correctly handle it.

Let me explain what i have and what i'm trying to do (i suppose it's the correct way of handle that scenario):

- The directive (panelMenu) that loads a template through templateUrl and define it's own controller with one property (visibilidad). (That property value is supposed to be gathered as the result of a service that i have working, but for the easiness of the example i will remove that part)

  ```
  .directive('panelMenu', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: './partials/panelMenu.html',
      replace: true,
      transclude: false,
      controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
          $scope.visibilidad = false;
      } ],
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      }
  };
  })
  ```
- The template (panelMenu.html) that is being loaded by the directive, that uses ng-if attached to the visibility property defined inside the directive controller to dinamycally add/remove the html.

panelMenu.html:

```
<div class="panel-menu" ng-if="visibilidad">
<a class="brand" href="#">Menú [Tablet] - Valor {{visibilidad}}</a>
</div>
```

And that's what i got from the browser console:

Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'panelMenu', required by directive 'ngIf', can't be found!

I have been reading a lot about how does works ng-if and scopes...but it's supposed that ng-if should inherit from the parent scope (controller defined on the directive). Do iam right?.

BTW, i'm using the custom directive on index.html like that:

```
<panel-menu></panel-menu>
```

Besides the main problem, i would want to know if i'm doing it correctly, or if the ng-if condition should be placed on the directive tag (accessing the service that i had mentioned before to get the value) instead on the html template.

Thanks in advance for all.

Comment: I'm having troubles with this as well. Just curious, have you tried using template instead of templateUrl.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having trouble with this issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/I7ibaj66hLX7uAgfENdk?p=preview

It appears to be relegated to string values - - - in my plnkr, I was able to get booleans to function properly